# how to pass int value in text view from 1 activity to another in android

Tags: android

I am learning android development and my mentor gave me assignment to pass an integer value in textview from main activity to second activity.

I am confused and dont know what to do. What should I do now ? How to write this code on android studio ?

Comment: Show your code to start the second activity.

Answer (score 1):

pass integer

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myInt", 123); you want to pass
startActivity(intent);
```

retrieve integer

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int myInteger = intent.getIntExtra("myInt", 0); // 0 is default

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(myInteger));
}
```